# What is the problem in my "sumAtBis" code?

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

i am here to ask about the problem about this function that calculates the sum at a given depth in a tree, it is working in all cases but the last level, the compiler is giving me this :
`[Done] exited with code=3221225477 in 0.309 seconds`
and this is my code and everything you need(there is more other functions and stuff but i think this is enough):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
typedef int element;
typedef struct node{
    element e;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * right;
}node;
typedef node * tree;
int isEmpty(tree a){
    return a==NULL;
}
element root(tree a){
    return a->e;
}
tree left(tree a){
    return a->left;
}
tree right(tree a){
    return a->right;
}
int max(int x,int y){
    return x>y?x:y;
}
int sumAtBis(tree a, int n, int i){
    if(i==n){
        if(isEmpty(a))
            return 0;
        else
            return root(a);
    }
    return sumAtBis(left(a),n,i+1)+sumAtBis(right(a),n,i+1);
    
}
int sumAt(tree a, int n){
    return sumAtBis(a,n,0);
}
int testSumAtBis(tree a, int n, int i){
    return sumAt(a,n)==0?1:0;
}
int testSumAt(tree a, int n){
    return testSumAtBis(a,n,0)==0?1:0;
}
int main(){
    node g={-1,NULL,NULL};
    node f={1,NULL,NULL};
    node e={0,&f,&g};
    node d={0,NULL,NULL};
    node c={1,&d,&e};
    node b={-1,NULL,NULL};
    node a={1,&c,&b};
    tree v;
    v=&a;
    printf("%d\n",sumAt(v,3));
    return 0;
}
```

i tried printing the value of i at each level when but it also gives an error so i can't know, also i tried to ask Copilot and Gemini but they didn't help

Comment: `3221225477` is the same as `0xC0000005`, which is a well-known result for a crash due to access (point) error. In short, you try to use (dereference) an invalid pointer.

Comment: As a hint, think about those leaf nodes, where you can essentially call `sumAtBis(NULL, ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Within the function `sumAtBis`

```
int sumAtBis(tree a, int n, int i){
    if(i==n){
        if(isEmpty(a))
            return 0;
        else
            return root(a);
    }
    return sumAtBis(left(a),n,i+1)+sumAtBis(right(a),n,i+1);
    
}
```

there is no check whether `left( a )` or `right( a )` are null pointers. So the function can invoke undefined behavior.

Actually the function `sumAtBis` is redundant. It is enough to define the function `sumAt` as for example

```
long long int sumAt( tree a, size_t n )
{
    if ( isEmpty( a ) )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return n == 0 ? 
            root( a ) : 
            sumAt( left( a ), n - 1 ) + sumAt( right( a ), n - 1 );
    }
}
```

And correspondingly the call of `printf` will look like

```
printf( "%lld\n", sumAt( v, n ) );
         ^^^^
```

Also using the typedef name `tree`

```
typedef node * tree;
```

is not a good idea because you can not define the type `const node *` by means of this typedef name because `const tree` is equivalent to `node * const` instead of the required type `const node *` and this type should be used in the parameter declaration of the function because the function does not change nodes of the tree.

Comment: i have function `isLeaf` that checks if a node is a leaf, do you think it will help ?

Comment: @AMIS7 In the function definition I showed there is no need to use the function isLeaf. On the other hand, If you want to sum values only of leafs then indeed this function will be useful.